# A count of started touches is not equal to count of finished touches

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, uitouch

I have the following code for testing purposes:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [self customTouchHandler:touches];
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [self customTouchHandler:touches];
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [self customTouchHandler:touches];
}

- (void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [self customTouchHandler:touches];
}
- (void)customTouchHandler:(NSSet *)touches
{
    for(UITouch* touch in touches){
        if(touch.phase == UITouchPhaseBegan)
            touchesStarted++;
        if(touch.phase == UITouchPhaseEnded || touch.phase == UITouchPhaseCancelled)
            touchesFinished++;
    }
    NSLog(@"%d / %d", touchesStarted, touchesFinished);
}
```

I suppose that when there is no touch on the screen, `touchesStarted` should be always equal to `touchesFinished`, but I have a pretty strange output:

```
2014-04-16 13:44:27.780 App[5925:60b] 2 / 0
2014-04-16 13:44:27.911 App[5925:60b] 2 / 1
```

I pressed the screen with two fingers and then released them almost (but not) in the same time.

Am I missing something? Multiple touches enabled for my view. By the way, the view is `SKView` and the code belongs to my custom `SKScene`.

**UPDATE**

As many of you cannot reproduce this strange behaviour, I've prepared a sample Xcode project: https://www.dropbox.com/s/qmgxka1gtgwquio/TapTest.zip

Try to tapping with two fingers at same time many times. `touchesStarted` must be equal to `touchesEnded` when you remove the fingers, right? But they are not. Here is my output:

```
2014-04-24 12:49:06.359 TapTest[8207:60b] 1 / 0
2014-04-24 12:49:06.376 TapTest[8207:60b] 2 / 0
2014-04-24 12:49:06.458 TapTest[8207:60b] 2 / 0
2014-04-24 12:49:06.460 TapTest[8207:60b] 2 / 1
2014-04-24 12:49:06.491 TapTest[8207:60b] 2 / 2
2014-04-24 12:49:07.325 TapTest[8207:60b] 3 / 2
2014-04-24 12:49:07.342 TapTest[8207:60b] 4 / 2
2014-04-24 12:49:07.408 TapTest[8207:60b] 4 / 2
2014-04-24 12:49:07.410 TapTest[8207:60b] 4 / 3
2014-04-24 12:49:07.426 TapTest[8207:60b] 4 / 3
2014-04-24 12:49:07.441 TapTest[8207:60b] 4 / 4
2014-04-24 12:49:07.842 TapTest[8207:60b] 6 / 4
2014-04-24 12:49:07.925 TapTest[8207:60b] 6 / 4
2014-04-24 12:49:07.941 TapTest[8207:60b] 6 / 5
2014-04-24 12:49:08.042 TapTest[8207:60b] 8 / 5
2014-04-24 12:49:08.125 TapTest[8207:60b] 8 / 6
2014-04-24 12:49:08.259 TapTest[8207:60b] 9 / 6
2014-04-24 12:49:08.293 TapTest[8207:60b] 9 / 6
2014-04-24 12:49:08.308 TapTest[8207:60b] 9 / 7
2014-04-24 12:49:08.425 TapTest[8207:60b] 10 / 7
2014-04-24 12:49:08.442 TapTest[8207:60b] 11 / 7
2014-04-24 12:49:08.444 TapTest[8207:60b] 11 / 7
2014-04-24 12:49:08.492 TapTest[8207:60b] 11 / 8
2014-04-24 12:49:08.575 TapTest[8207:60b] 11 / 9
2014-04-24 12:49:08.642 TapTest[8207:60b] 12 / 9
2014-04-24 12:49:08.659 TapTest[8207:60b] 13 / 9
2014-04-24 12:49:08.660 TapTest[8207:60b] 13 / 9
2014-04-24 12:49:08.692 TapTest[8207:60b] 13 / 9
2014-04-24 12:49:08.694 TapTest[8207:60b] 13 / 10
2014-04-24 12:49:08.708 TapTest[8207:60b] 13 / 10
2014-04-24 12:49:08.741 TapTest[8207:60b] 13 / 11
2014-04-24 12:49:08.792 TapTest[8207:60b] 14 / 11
2014-04-24 12:49:08.809 TapTest[8207:60b] 15 / 11
2014-04-24 12:49:08.810 TapTest[8207:60b] 15 / 11
2014-04-24 12:49:08.890 TapTest[8207:60b] 15 / 11
2014-04-24 12:49:08.892 TapTest[8207:60b] 15 / 12
2014-04-24 12:49:08.908 TapTest[8207:60b] 15 / 13
2014-04-24 12:49:09.042 TapTest[8207:60b] 17 / 13
2014-04-24 12:49:09.141 TapTest[8207:60b] 17 / 14
2014-04-24 12:49:09.242 TapTest[8207:60b] 19 / 14
2014-04-24 12:49:09.341 TapTest[8207:60b] 19 / 14
2014-04-24 12:49:09.358 TapTest[8207:60b] 19 / 15
2014-04-24 12:49:09.441 TapTest[8207:60b] 21 / 15
2014-04-24 12:49:09.525 TapTest[8207:60b] 21 / 15
2014-04-24 12:49:09.542 TapTest[8207:60b] 21 / 15
2014-04-24 12:49:09.559 TapTest[8207:60b] 21 / 16
2014-04-24 12:49:09.608 TapTest[8207:60b] 22 / 16
2014-04-24 12:49:09.625 TapTest[8207:60b] 23 / 16
2014-04-24 12:49:09.626 TapTest[8207:60b] 23 / 16
2014-04-24 12:49:09.708 TapTest[8207:60b] 23 / 16
2014-04-24 12:49:09.709 TapTest[8207:60b] 23 / 17
2014-04-24 12:49:09.774 TapTest[8207:60b] 23 / 18
2014-04-24 12:49:09.810 TapTest[8207:60b] 24 / 18
2014-04-24 12:49:09.826 TapTest[8207:60b] 25 / 18
2014-04-24 12:49:09.828 TapTest[8207:60b] 25 / 18
2014-04-24 12:49:09.908 TapTest[8207:60b] 25 / 18
2014-04-24 12:49:09.909 TapTest[8207:60b] 25 / 19
2014-04-24 12:49:09.974 TapTest[8207:60b] 25 / 20
2014-04-24 12:49:09.992 TapTest[8207:60b] 26 / 20
2014-04-24 12:49:10.026 TapTest[8207:60b] 27 / 20
2014-04-24 12:49:10.027 TapTest[8207:60b] 27 / 20
2014-04-24 12:49:10.091 TapTest[8207:60b] 27 / 20
2014-04-24 12:49:10.094 TapTest[8207:60b] 27 / 21
2014-04-24 12:49:10.125 TapTest[8207:60b] 27 / 22
```

Comment: why you call the method on the touchesMoved. only check with touchesBegan and touchesEnded

Comment: @SunnyShah it has no effect on the issue at hand. As method name states customTouchHandler can later be used to handle some custom touch that may or may not use touches moved.

Comment: @SunnyShah it doesn't matter. If I remove touchesMoved, the result will be the same

Comment: yaaa i show the if condition

Comment: I don't know internal implementation of SKView, but I would call [super] implementation for each of those methods.

Comment: @Andy thaks for comment. I tried that with no luck

Comment: does the class that you are showing the source code from has a subclass? i mean, is it possible that a subclass overrided -touchesEnded: and your -customTouchHandler: is not called in that case? Are you really on top of the responder chain?

Comment: @Michael no, it does not have any subclasses

Comment: I was unable to replicate this behavior. I used an SKView and your code from above, and the counts were always equal. It might be difficult to diagnose without the full codebase, so I would recommend stashing/committing/copying your project and slowly deleting parts of it until the behavior is more expected. If its still happening, you haven't removed the issue yet. If it stops happening, the issue is one of the last things that you deleted.

Comment: @Dan_Gabicoware, how did you touch the screen?

Comment: I tried to replicate the touches as described: pressing two fingers to the screen then releasing them both together, and then again almost together.

Comment: @AndreyGordeev do you have other views or just a single view in which you are testing your code? If you have multiple, do the other have userInteractionEnabled set to YES?. If there is only one, are you setting multipleTouchEnabled to YES or NO?

Comment: @AndreyGordeev Also cannot reproduce. Can you share the initialization code for touchesStarted & touchesFinished? Could be that you're using primitive types and 64-bit is jamming you up. You can try logging as NSNumber objects, just to be sure: `NSLog(@"%@ / %@", @(touchesStarted), @(touchesFinished));` -- and/or make sure you're initializing NSIntegers (not just int), etc. Long shot but if nobody else can repro, it's likely something you're doing that we cannot see.

Comment: That's not only my problem actually. Here one guy experiences exactly the same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23194805/touchesendedwithevent-is-not-called

Comment: Try adding some logic to count the "UITouchPhaseStationary", those are probably your missing touches.

Also I guess you could simply log out all the objects in the touches set, and actually see where they are and what phase they are in, instead of just counting them :)

Comment: @TheisEgeberg may be you're right, but missing touches are not suppose to be in that phase! All the touches are ended. I don't have 5 of my fingers on the screen as the final count says (27 / 22) :)

Comment: Ok, I found a way how to always reproduce it (at least on the ipad simualtor 7.1). Touch the screen with 2 fingers, release 1 finger (the 2nd one is still "touching" the screen). (In this moment, now delegate method is triggerd).  Now, swipe the touching finger out from the screen...  And there you are :)

Comment: I think there is no guarantee that you'll receive the touches ended because of strange cases like dragging your finger out of the screen. T. began >= T. ended ... you must not rely on this counting and better use other strategy.

Comment: What kind of strategy? I just want to know how many touches on my view, thats all

Comment: Based on that last update, it sounds like it might be turning into a touchesMoved event.

Comment: @Inafziger what do you mean? `touchesMoved` is not affecting on the result at all, try to add it

Comment: You will likely need to track the touches manually in a CFDictionaryRef

Comment: @AndreyGordeev That's my point.  You might be getting a touch began, and then instead of a touch end you are getting a touch moved.

Answer (score 2):

Also have this problem.

Only solution i found at this moment based on observing touch phase:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    NSLog(@"Began %lu of %lu", [touches count], [event.allTouches count]);

    for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
        [touch addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"phase" options:0 context:nil];
    }
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    NSLog(@"Ended %lu of %lu", [touches count], [event.allTouches count]);
}

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {

    if ([object isKindOfClass:[UITouch class]]) {
        UITouch *touch = object;
        NSLog(@"Touch %lu phase: %ld", (unsigned long)[touch hash], [touch phase]);
        if (touch.phase == UITouchPhaseEnded || touch.phase == UITouchPhaseCancelled) {
            NSLog(@"Touch %lu ended", (unsigned long)[touch hash]);
            [touch removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"phase"];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears this is a bug in SKView's `touchesBegan:` method. From what I can tell, Apple is using a dictionary to associate each `UITouch` with the object that the touch methods should be forwarded to. From my testing it appears that if there are multiple touches that begin at the same time, only one of the touches gets added to the dictionary. As a result, your scene won't ever receive the touch-related method calls for the other touches, which is why you are seeing the difference between touchesStarted and touchesFinished.

If you subclass SKView and override the `touchesBegan:` method, your scene should get the correct calls.

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
        NSSet *newSet = [NSSet setWithObject:touch];
        [super touchesBegan:newSet withEvent:event];
    }
}
```

This fixed the problem for me, but it's possible there might be some side effects from calling the super method multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

Cannot comment, so will answer here. You coud print all handlers like this, maybe it helps:

```
- (void)customTouchHandler:(NSSet *)touches
{
    static int handlerCounter = 0;
    handlerCounter++;
    for(UITouch* touch in touches){
        NSLog(@"%d: %d", handlerCounter, touch.phase);
        if(touch.phase == UITouchPhaseBegan)
            touchesStarted++;
        if(touch.phase == UITouchPhaseEnded || touch.phase == UITouchPhaseCancelled)
            touchesFinished++;
    }
    NSLog(@"%d / %d", touchesStarted, touchesFinished);
}
```

Is it possible to switch(touch.phase) in obj-c? Is the "or" in the second if evaluated correctly, try using brackts.

Comment: The same result: `59 / 55`. Thanks for responding

Answer (score 0):

If you are using more than one finger you should include `self.view.multipleTouchEnabled = YES;` in your `init`.

I ran some extensive tests on your supplied code and the only time the numbers do not match up is when the taping occurs very fast from a combination of either one or both fingers. In this case, iOS looses track of the contact the current state.

This is very similar to when a sprite bounces up and down very quickly on another sprite which sometimes causes a wrong contact state in the didBeginContact.

There is currently no way you can get around this using multiple touches. If you use a single touch, your count will always (at least in my tests) match.

Comment: If I set `self.view.multipleTouchEnabled = YES` the result wuold be the same, I tried that too.

Comment: "In this case, iOS looses track of the contact the current state." - it seems so. My question is how to avoid this? :)

Comment: Also, there is at least one game in AppStore where touch handling performs without this problem - Moon Lander

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem before ([touchesEnded:withEvent: is not called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23194805/touchesendedwithevent-is-not-called)).

My testing revealed that touchedEnded was not being called 100% of the time. My solution: Place the four touch handling methods in the AppDelegate.m file and forward the touches to your view controller. I have no idea why this works, but I didn't have any issues after doing that.