# touchesEnded:withEvent: is not called

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, touches

If I tap the screen too fast with two fingers, `touchesBegan` is called, but `touchesEnded` is not called for one of the touches.

I've googled like crazy and this seems to be a serious issue that people have been having since at least 2010. Apparently it hasn't been fixed. Does anyone know of a workaround for this or is there a way to determine touches without the 4 methods or gesture recognizers? (They tend to cause a delay which isn't practical for me.)

By the way, all 4 methods are implemented. I would appreciate any thoughts on this as I'm about to lose my mind. Thanks.

Comment: add some code for check what's problem .

Comment: Please post the touch delegates as you have implemented them

Comment: The method is not being called. Whatever is inside the method should be irrelevant. There's been many questions posted just like this and no one has an answer. I think I'll just have to submit a bug report to Apple.

Comment: Try checking for other UITouch objects in the touches NSSet. You can do this by using NSLog(@"%@", [touches allObjects]);

Comment: The UITouch objects are normal. The touchesEnded is simply not being called when it is supposed to be.(when 2 or more touches happen too quickly)

Comment: I am having exactly the same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23105891/a-count-of-started-touches-is-not-equal-to-count-of-finished-touches

Comment: What about using UIGestureRecognizer? Maybe it will solve your problem.

Comment: UIGestureRecognizers don't suite for such tasks, because they have a delay before firing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose this is a little late and Apple may have fixed the issue, but my solution was simply to place the four touch handling methods in the AppDelegate.m file and then forward the touches to my view controller. I don't know why this works or how I figured it out, but that was my solution. I was wrong to assume the Xcode sample project had the touches working properly, but now I know. Hope this helps someone.